# Trying to rewrite a stored procedure so it is possible to pass on a @tableName from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass a table name to a stored procedure in SQL Server.

I have understood that this is not possible by default to do because of risks for `injection malicious attacks`.

When googled around, I have understood that this is anyway possible to do.

I will try to create this anyway as I have understood that it is possible somehow by declaring a `string query` like I try to do below. Knowing about the risks, I will try to do this anyway as I really like to create all code in procedures to make it more clean. The code will also only be used on my own computer.

The original code that I have for the stored procedure looks like this. I have put `@tableName` here as a parameter which then *doesn't work* as it isn't possible be default to pass on a tableName here.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getLastFeatureUpdate
    @maxDateTime BIGINT = 0,
    @tableName nvarchar
AS
    SELECT
        test.FeatureNbr,
        test.DayTime,
        test.Val
    FROM
        @tableName test 
    WHERE
        DayTime = (SELECT MAX(DayTime)
                   FROM @tableName
                   WHERE FeatureNbr = test.FeatureNbr 
                     AND DayTime <= @maxDateTime)
```

Now comes the version, I am trying to do in order to **re-write** the above code so it will work by passing on the `@tableName` parameter - I get 2 errors for this code:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@maxDateTime"

`EXEC sp_executesql @FullQuery` shows error:

> Error: Procedure: [dbo].[getLastFeatureUpdate] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[sp_executesql]

I then wonder what I can be doing wrong in my code?

Rewritten stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getLastFeatureUpdate
    @maxDateTime BIGINT = 0,
    @tableName nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FullQuery nvarchar(1000)

    SET @FullQuery = N'SELECT test.FeatureNbr, test.DayTime, test.Val FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' test 
                     WHERE DayTime = ( SELECT MAX(DayTime) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' WHERE FeatureNbr = test.FeatureNbr AND DayTime <= @maxDateTime )'

    EXEC sp_executesql @FullQuery
END
```

EDIT:

C# code to execute the Stored Procedure:

```
        void getLastFeatureUpdate()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            {
                conn.Open();

                // 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getLastFeatureUpdate", conn);

                // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@maxDateTime", 201010222045));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tableName", "testTable"));

                // execute the command
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // iterate through results, printing each to console
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Int64 v1 = (Int64)rdr["DayTime"];
                        int v2 = (Int16)rdr["FeatureNbr"];
                        double v3 = (double)rdr["Val"];

                        MessageBox.Show(v1 + "," + v2 + "," + v3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should declare your table name as type "sysname", just FYI. "sysname" is the type of all schema objects... table names, column names, default constraint names, foreign key names, index names, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define and pass in the parameters when using `sp_executesql` for a query that takes parameters:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    @FullQuery, 
    N'@maxDateTime float(53)',  
    @maxDateTime ;
```

I will say that using a dynamic table name is a sign that you have a bad table design, specifically when you have similar data split into multiple tables rather than a single table with columns to categorize the data.

Comment: I will hardcode everything to have unique names. This can't be wrong when I do it correctly. There will not be any user input in the software.

Comment: Thanks, this almost seems to work now. Though I get this error when executing the code: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.'` I am not sure how to pass this as the parameter in C# if I understand?

Comment: @coding Try adding `N` in front of the string (answer updated).

Comment: Or pass it by name, `@params = N'@maxDateTime float(53)'`

Comment: Passing a date/time as float is suspicious, though. The value you were passing in the previous question was not a date/time value, it was an integer that was out of range of the float representation of a date/time.

Comment: @madreflection Yes it is true for the datetime in my other post as you say. But for the problem itself to understand the problem. I pass it like this in `C#` where `ntext/nchar/nvarchar` is needed somehow? `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@maxDateTime", 201010222045)); cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tableName", "testTable"));`

Comment: @Stanley sorry, I missed the `N` in your updated answer, - I tried to put `N` in front of the string as you did in your answer and I got this error when trying to execute: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 't'.'` (I EDIT my post to see my C# code also)

Comment: Using `AddWithValue` (don't do that!) to add `@maxDateTime` with a value of `201010222045` is going to pass the value as `bigint`, and then coerce it to `float`, probably in the engine. Your predicate is going to have to coerce a value to compare. Coercing `DayTime` to `float` will make it fail because it's greater than the entire `datetime` range. Coercing `@maxDateTime` to `datetime` will overflow and error. You need to convert `201010222045` to a .NET `DateTime` value, and use `Add` to add the parameter, specifying `SqlDbType.DateTime`. That takes all the guesswork out of it.

Comment: @madreflection I will need to look into the `DateTime` format as you mention later. I am not sure how the format will be. I have changed so I use `BIGINT` as test for the actual error that I am receiving. So I use that everywhere, in the table and procedure. But still get the error: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 't'.'` This seems to be another problem?

Comment: I am not sure how to pass it in another way like this? `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@maxDateTime", 201010222045));` Isn't `AddWithValue` another syntax or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: `AddWithValue` is convenient but, at least with SQL Server, it's a bad option.  It has nuances and you're square in the middle of being affected by them. Read: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)  You need to read the documentation on the `Add` methods. Don't just guess. As for the exception, you've made changes without sharing them so there's no way to help you with that.

Comment: That is good to know. I must read this. I know that someone from another post I had said the same not to use `AddWithValue` and instead use `Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter` so I got confused there now. I edited my post where I **only** changed from `float (53)` to `BIGINT`. However I have found the problem. The problem is: `@tableName nvarchar`. It should be declared: `@tableName text` in the procedure and then it works. But it seems that `text` is not supported in later SQL versions. So I am not sure how to declare this as a string is passed here from C#?

Comment: As you were told on the last question, `text` and `ntext` are deprecated. Use `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)` instead. Also, changing to `BIGINT` is not the correct reaction. Change it to `DATETIME` and pass a `DateTime` value.

Comment: I was told: `varchar or nvarchar` not `nvarchar(max)` but `nvarchar(max)` did work. I should use this then so I don't use `text` so it will be compatible with newer versions. As I mentioned. I changed to BIGINT just to find the other actual problem. I will dig into how the format is for `DateTime`.

Comment: Note that the `DateTime` type doesn't have a format. String representations have a format, and you parse that format to `DateTime`.

Comment: Yes this is what I ment I think. I was thinking of `DateTime` as I use it in C#. I just need to see how I will store it in the table and to pass it on. It is perheps in the same way then. I really have to use `DateTime` so everything will be correct. Thank you for pointing this out also.